# How to generate constraints dynamically in scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize, quadratic-programming

Well what I was trying to do was to model the following using scipy.optimize.minimize.
[image]

[image]
[image]

What I'm trying to optimize is this function with its constraints:
[image]
[image]
Here variable V is a list of variables, list's length is equal to the size of Omega.
What I did so far is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# set of concepts
M = ['linear algebra','seq2seq', 'artificial neural network','pointer networks']

#subchapters
S1=['linear algebra', 'differential calculus','backpropagation']
S2=['linear algebra','seq2seq', 'artificial neural network']
S3=['linear algebra','seq2seq', 'artificial neural network','pointer networks']

#vector representation of the subchapter in the concept space
x=[[1,1,0,0],
   [1,1,1,0],
   [1,1,1,1]]

# set of prerequisite relations among subchapters (entered manually for testing)
Omega = [(1, 2),(2,3),(1,3)]

# number of concepts
m = len(M)

# define of theta and lambda constants (manual)
theta = 2
lamda = 1

# matrix A is a m x m matrix , where m is the number of concepts
# it represents the prerequisite relations among concepts
# A is generated randomly
np.random.seed(43)
#A = np.zeros((m,m), dtype = int)
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(m,m))

# define the slack variable V as an array of size equal to len(Omega)
V = np.empty(len(Omega), dtype=float)

bnds=[]
# bounds -1 and 1 , create the array
# -1 <= a[i][j] <= 1
bnds_a_s_t = [bnds.append((-1, 1)) for _ in range(np.size(A))]
# bounds for the slack variable V, V is positive
bnds_V_i_j = [bnds.append((0,np.inf)) for _ in range(np.size(V))]

#constraints
cons=[]
#equality constraint
#a[s][t] + a[t][s] = 0
def equality_constraint(X):
    A_no_flatten=X[:len(X)-len(Omega)]
    #reconstruct matrix A
    A=np.reshape(A_no_flatten,(m,m))

    for s in range(m):
        for t in range(m):
            r=A[s][t]+A[t][s]
            #r=0 constraint
            con = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: r} 
            cons.append(con)

# inequality constraint
#x[i].T @ (C[i][j] * A) @ x[j]
def inequality_constraint(X,x):
    for couple in Omega:
        # get the i and j
        i = couple[0]
        j = couple[1]
        
        #initialize C to 1s
        C = np.full((m,m), 1, dtype = int)
        # take all elements from X except last len(Omega) elements
        A_no_flatten=X[:len(X)-len(Omega)]
        # reconstruct list V
        V=X[-len(Omega):]
        #index for V
        f=0
        #reconstruct matrix A
        A=np.reshape(A_no_flatten,(m,m))
        
        #construct C[i][j]
        for s in range(m):
            for t in range(m):
                if x[i][t]>0 or x[j][s]>0:
                    C[s][t]=0
                else:
                    C[s][t]=1
        
        first= x[i].T
        second = C*A
        third = x[j]
        
        first_sec = first@second
        res=first_sec@third
        ineq_con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda X: res -theta +V[f]}
        f+=1
        cons.append(ineq_con)
        
# arguments passed to the function
# here we pass x matrix 
# arguments are passed and used in constraints and in the objective function
# the objective function will minimize A and V which are matrix A and slack variable V
arguments=(x,)

# objective function
def objective(X, x):
    A_no_flatten=X[:len(X)-len(Omega)]
    # reconstruct list V
    V=X[-len(Omega):]
    #reconstruct matrix A
    A=np.reshape(A_no_flatten,(m,m))
    
    # sum of square V
    sum_square=0.0
    for it in V:
        sum_square+=it**2
    # sum of square V * lambda
    sum_square_lambda=sum_square*lamda
    
    return norm(A, 1) + sum_square_lambda

# list of variables to pass to the objective function
#pass the x0.flatten() which is the A + V combined, and then when in objective function we recreate them
# the first one A is all except the last s items where s is the size of V
# and then V is the rest

B = A.flatten()
p0 = np.append(B,V)

# scipy minimize
sol = minimize(objective, x0 = p0, args=arguments, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print(sol.x)
```

What I get is the following:

```
[-7.73458566e-010  0.00000000e+000  4.99999997e-001  1.00000000e+000
  1.00000000e+000  0.00000000e+000 -5.00000003e-001  1.00000000e+000
  1.00000000e+000  1.00000000e+000  4.99999997e-001 -7.73458566e-010
 -7.73458566e-010  0.00000000e+000  4.99999997e-001 -7.73458566e-010
  6.01347002e-154  1.07176259e-311  0.00000000e+000]
```

Which doesn't respect the constraints and is not what I expected

What I don't know is that is it correct to add constraints like that, because I don't seem to call the constraints function, and I need to add them in a loop, and each function depends on X which is the list to minimize.
When I print the `cons` array it is empty and I know, but I didn't find another way to add the constraint `a[s][t]+a[t][s]=0` and the other one, I don't know if my approach is correct, thank you for your help in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: The constraints need to be formed in advance, thus your list of constraints `cons` is empty when calling `minimize`. For the equality constraints, this could be achieved by calling `equality_constraint(p0)` before `minimize`. However, I'd strongly recommend simplifying the constraint code as it is cumbersome IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate more your answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but it may get you started. As already mentioned in the comments, your list of constraints `cons` is empty when passed to the `minimize` method. So let's consider your first equality constraint. There are a few problems:

- Each time you call the function `equality_constraint`, you'd append new constraints to your list `cons`.
- Since you pass each constraint `A[s][t] + A[t][s] == 0` as scalar function, it is quite cumbersome. Instead, you could use a single vector-valued function:

```py
def constraint1(X):
    A_no_flatten = X[:len(X)-len(Omega)]
    A = np.reshape(A_no_flatten,(m,m))
    return A.flatten() + A.T.flatten()
```

As the name indicates, the `.flatten()` method flattens the matrix to a vector and `A.T` is just the transpose of `A`.  Now you can add this constraint:

```py
cons = []
cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1})
```

Proceed similarly for the other constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I would really like to know if it's a good way to define the inequality constraint above, which has the i and j, and do you suggest a better method to do it when the number of i->j relations increases? Thank you in advance